# How do I parse "dd.MM.yyyy G" to ISO-Date in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime

Hey guys I have the date `"01.01.1000 AD"`(SimpleDate) as String and `dd.MM.yyyy G`(SimpleFormat) and need to parse it into a Standard ISO-Date in the form `1995-12-31T23:59:59Z` (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'`)

my actual code is:

```
public static String getISODate(String simpleDate, String simpleFormat, String isoFormat) throws ParseException {
    Date date;
    if (simpleFormat.equals("long")) {
        date = new Date(Long.parseLong(simpleDate));
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(simpleFormat);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        // or else testcase
        // "1964-02-24" would
        // result "1964-02-23"
        date = df.parse(simpleDate);
    }
    return getISODate(date, isoFormat);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how do I do that?

Comment: What calendar does 01.01.1000 AD refers to?

Comment: Have a look at [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), especially the `parse` and `format` methods.

Comment: With a 1000 AD date, you have to take interesting phenomena into account such as the transition from Julian to Gregorian in 1582, and the fact that a location will have had a multitude of different time zones in the past 1000 years.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format

Comment: `String isoFormat` is null in my case

Comment: @Raffaele it should be the Gregorian Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String string = "01.01.1000 AD";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(string);
```

The G in the date format stands for era.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I still get there an exeption
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01.01.1000 AD"`

Comment: I can reproduce your error if I set the locale like so: `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG", Locale.GERMANY);`, so it looks like a locale issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will hopefully help [tricky with standard jdk, but at least possible - and JSR 310 doesn't support this feature :-( ]:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy GG", Locale.US);
DateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date d = df.parse("01.01.1000 AD");
    System.out.println(iso.format(d)); // year-of-era => 1000-01-01 (not iso!!!)

    // now let us configure gregorian/julian date change right for ISO-8601
    GregorianCalendar isoCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    isoCalendar.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
    iso.setCalendar(isoCalendar);
    System.out.println(iso.format(d)); // proleptic iso year: 1000-01-06
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And by the way, related to historic dates there is no sense to format in ISO including hours or even milliseconds. Therefore I have intentionally left out the time part.

Comment: And in order to avoid DST effects it is wise to set in both format objects df and iso the timezone to UTC. Good luck.

Comment: the problem is i need it as iso-date for my Solr-Index, and Solr can only work with ISO-date if u want to search facet 8thats what i need to do)

Comment: Now that works for me, the Problem was the wrong locale
'public static String getISODate(String simpleDate, String simpleFormat, String isoFormat) throws ParseException {
        Date date;
        if (simpleFormat.equals("long")) {
            date = new Date(Long.parseLong(simpleDate));
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(simpleFormat, Locale.US);
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            date = df.parse(simpleDate);
        }
        return getISODate(date, isoFormat);
    }`

Comment: First thing to note: With Locale.US the code will successfully parse. Second: 01.01.1000 AD is correctly translated to 1000-01-06 (pure ISO). Third: Because of lack of support in java I leave out the historical detail that in most countries of Europe at that time the year did not start at first of January, but in March or April. Fourth: If you really need time part for solr-interface just set it to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
String date = "01.01.1000 AD";   
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy GG");   
System.out.println(parserSDF.parse(date));
```

Comment: `MM` must be used for months.

Answer (score 0):

Try it may be help:

```
public static String getISODate(String simpleDate, String simpleFormat, String isoFormat) throws ParseException {
    Date date;
    if (simpleFormat.equals("long")) {
        date = new Date(Long.parseLong(simpleDate));
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(simpleFormat);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
        // or else testcase
        // "1964-02-24" would
        // result "1964-02-23"
        date = df.parse(simpleDate);
    }
    return getISODate(date, isoFormat);
}
```

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ is not a valid timezone identifier, but a pattern string for SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: also still `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01.01.1000 AD"`

Comment: That is because for the timezone you entered, the moment 00:00:00 01-01-1000 AD does not exist. You will see the same error for a 1 hour period every year, if you pick a date/time instant in the hour that is skipped at the start of daylight saving time.