# Covert timestamp to json iso8601 in java

Tags: java, json, date, iso8601

I have an object --> `public timestamp date;` which gives me a date like :

> 2012-08-07T07:47:46 - 0000+0....

but I want:

> "2012-08-07T07:47:46**Z**"

How can I parse to json date iso 8601 with the "z" at the end?

Comment: almost definitely duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current moment in ISO 8601 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format)

Comment: yes, i reconize, i have not see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Joda libraries, what you need is to convert ISO8061 to ISO8061 but with UTC timezone. [Joda Docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html)

Alternatively `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")`

Comment: I use the second solution :
Date myoldformatDate = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String mynewformatDate =  df.format(date);

 Input :

2015-03-30T15:56:13-000-00..

Output :

 2015-03-30T15:56:13Z

Thank you for your help.