# How to convert current date and time in 2016-02-14T15:50:39Z format?

Tags: java

I want to convert system date and time in 2016-02-14T15:50:39Z format. How to achieve using java?

Comment: You ever heared about SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Please please please READ -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html !!

Comment: Ya I heard but I am not able to convert so I asked. Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Similar to [this other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3914404/642706), but that one truncates to whole minute whereas this Question truncates to whole second.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .toString()
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.678901Z

## Details

The other answers use old outmoded classes.

## ISO 8601

Your desired format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The `Z` on the end stands for `Zulu` which means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, use the built-in java.time framework.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values.

### Instant

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the time line in UTC. Its [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) method gets the current moment. As of Java 8 Update 74 that `now` method gets the current moment with [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution but future versions may get up to the full [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution which can fit in an `Instant`.

The [`Instant::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method generates a String just as you desire, using groups of digits (0, 3, 6, or 9) as needed for the fractional second.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString();  // Example: 2016-02-14T15:50:39.123Z
```

#### Truncate fractional second

If do not care about the fraction of a second, as seen in your Question’s example, truncate with a call to [`with`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-), passing the [`ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#NANO_OF_SECOND) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
String output = Instant.now().with( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 ).toString();  // Example: 2016-02-14T15:50:39Z (no '.123' at end)
```

Even simpler, call [`truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method, passing a [`ChronoUnit.SECONDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MINUTES) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
String output = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString();
```

If you want to truncate to whole *minute* rather than whole *second*, see [this other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3914404/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date dt=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(dt);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

You can try several others date formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

use simple date format below is example :

```
Date curDate = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    String DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    try {
        Date strToDate = format.parse(DateToStr);
        System.out.println(strToDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```