# Android parse date Simple Date Format

Tags: java, android, parsing, simpledateformat

I been stuck trying to parse the following date format below:

2016-04-27T00:00:00+10:00

I've tried many combinations and can't seem to get it to work.

I would have thought this would work as it make the most sense to me - 
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unable to parse it as you are not using the correct format. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String input = "2016-04-27T00:00:00+10:00";
Date date = sf.parse(input);
```

Output:

```
Tue Apr 26 14:00:00 GMT 2016
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, Thanks. I was adding the single quotations around the Z which was wrong as well.

Comment: @Petersicecream If you are doing something like `'Z'` then it looks for the literal `Z` and since you are not getting the literal but the TimeZone it fails.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for JSON parsing, you can simply annotate date field with **@JsonFormat** Annotation. Here's an example:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone="GMT")
public Date date;
```