# JSON, HTML: What is the time format as such called 2001-07-26T20:52:54Z?

Tags: javascript, iso

What is the date and time format like the following called, for example: 2001-07-26T20:52:54Z?

And how could I convert the date and time into that particular format and into string for JSON?

For example, if a user entered in 7/26/2001 and 20:52:54, I want it to be converted into 2001-07-26T20:52:54Z format.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its called [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) data format.

> ```
> Date:                          2016-08-19
> Combined date and time in UTC: 2016-08-19T19:03:01+00:00
>                                2016-08-19T19:03:01Z
>                                20160819T190301Z
> Week:                          2016-W33
> Date with week number:         2016-W33-5
> Date without year:             --08-19
> Ordinal date:                  2016-232
> ```

For conversion, you could use [`Date#toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

> The **`toISOString()`** method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```js
var today = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(today.toISOString()); // Returns 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z123
```

Example

```js
function convert() {
    var date = document.forms.iso.date.value,
        time = document.forms.iso.time.value,
        dateTime = new Date(date + ' ' + time + ' UTC');
    document.getElementById('iso').innerHTML = dateTime.toISOString();
}
```

```html
<form name="iso">
    date: <input type="text" name="date" value="7/26/2001"/><br />
    time: <input type="text"name="time" value="20:52:54" /><br />
    <button onclick="convert();">Convert</button>
</form>
<div id="iso"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth info! Do you mind showing what and how the user should be inputting, using `<input/>`, to be passed properly and formatted into the ISO 8601 format?

Comment: @JoKo, please see edit. don't forget to put the `UTC` to the string, because if not, you input a local time and get the a different zulu time.

Comment: sorry but in exactly what format is the user supposed to enter in the information? For example, for the date, they can't just manually put in 10/5/2001.

Comment: it's just like the example values.

Comment: sorry but is that supposed to be the placeholder?

Comment: i do not understand the question.

Comment: so if a user were to enter `7/20/2005` for date and `20:52:20` for time into the inputs, it will automatically translate it and reformat itself to `20 July 2005 20:52 UTC`?

Comment: yes, that`s right.

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept the answer and upvote. Before I do, one more quick question, I got it to work but after following: `var newDateTime = new Date(startDate + startTime + ' UTC');` and `var timeStart = newDateTime.toISOString();`, and console logged `timeStart` and got `2001-05-20T20:11:22.000Z` but would like to get rid of the `.000`, so like `2001-05-20T20:11:22Z`. How can I do so? Thank you again

Comment: you could replace the dot and last zeroes with an empty string, like `timeStart = timeStart.replace('.000', '');`.

Comment: But that would only apply in the case of `.000`, correct? Is there a way that applies in all cases? Just to leave out the milliseconds.

Comment: then use a regular expression like `timeStart = timeStart.replace(/\.\d{3}/, '');`. it looks for the dot an thre digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp). As long as you know what that standard is called and google you should be able to figure out everything else.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
n.replace(/\.\d{3}/,"")

2016-09-16T06:38:12Z
```

Comment: "As long as you know what that standard is called" I'm pretty sure that's what OP was asking. Also, [w3schools is not the best resource](http://www.w3fools.com/) for reference. Decent for beginner information but MDN is a much better reference for particular functions.

Comment: @RezaS but before I accept the answer and upvote, how can I get rid of the `.376` that follows after? So would just want `2016-08-19T20:11:39Z`

Comment: @JoKo You can do that using a regular expression, or follow the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8563517/196917 and leave out the milliseconds part

Comment: @RezaS I tried but didn't work my end. To confirm could you show so I can accept the answer and upvote as well?

Comment: updated answer...

Comment: @RezaS thank you works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's called [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. If you're using Python simply call [isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method, for other languages see following links: [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format), [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript). Anyway google is really helpful there.