# How to convert ISOdate in String in JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB to save my data and in database i can see the date value like this

```
ISODate("2016-11-30T11:17:20.945Z")
```

but when i parse it in front-end it become like

```
createdOn : 1480582463992
```

I want to convert "ISODate("2016-11-30T11:17:20.945Z")" it in JAVA and not in js in such a way so that i can get string date value.

Thanks in advance

==============================================================

here is my java code

```
@Override
public List<Prescription> getcus(
        String id, String cid) {
    List<Prescription> listrescription = null;
    listrescription  = this.patientDBService.getPatientLastThreePrescription(id, cid);

    Prescription prre = new Prescription();
    for(Prescription i : listrescription){ 
        //Date dates = new Date();
        //i.getCreatedOn(); // getting the data from mongo like 1480582463992

    //no clue what to do here to get ISO date as in string
     }
    return listrescription;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217193/1746118

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: @nullpointer my question is just opposite of what you have suggested

Comment: In your question edit I cannot see any connection to MongoDB... So, as far as I understand your question, you query a document from Mongo and have problems getting the saved date value, is that right? If so, show your document (completely) and the code that you use to retrieve the document and the date value from that doc.

Comment: @mtj the ques is not about mongo but mongo default save the data in ISO format. one who are using mongo can answer this that is why i tagged it with mongo... yes i am getting the data from mongo but is iso format. and since mongo save the date in ISO so it also fetching it in ISO

Comment: @adasdasd No, mongo does *not* store a specific format. A date saved in mongo is stored in an internal date representation and only *displayed* in that format, if you use the mongo shell. Each language specific mongo driver will translate this into the specific date-type for the target language (at least the java driver does).

Comment: @mtj sorry my bad you are right i am saving the data in @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    protected Date createdOn;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    protected Date updatedOn;

Comment: but this is not the question that how i am saving... the question is now i can i covert ISO in string

Comment: Read the Date *object* via the mongo driver, convert the date using the methods found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129529/discussion-between-adasdasd-and-mtj).

Comment: @mtj java 6 or earier version doen't support Z as in different values but 0:00 and also i am still clueless what to do -_-

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't care about the time zone** you can use this method to parse the date format like "2017-06-19T05:27:26.000Z"

```
private static String convertMongoDate(String val){
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        String finalStr = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(val));
        System.out.println(finalStr);
        return finalStr;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: But it you DO care about the time zone, you can set it with `SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone`

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

```
 new Date("2016-11-30T11:17:20.945Z")
```

Comment: i want to do it with java

Comment: this will conflict with ISO date format on mongo because new date has its own format... editing the question with java code. can you check it out>

Comment: new Date with an ISO-Date string? This is neither related to the question nor a legal constructor parameter (apart from the fact that the Date(String) constructor is deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Timestamp in milliseconds
        long timestamp = 1480582463992L;

        // Converting timestamp to Instant
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);

        // Converting Instant to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // Printing the date and time
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality answers. Apart from explaining what your code does, you should post what it produces so that the OP can see whether he gets the same result as you when he runs your code. Essentially this question is asking how to convert a timestamp, i.e. milliseconds since the epoch, to a date. There are already many such questions on SO. Refer to this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+code%3AofEpochMilli). As such this question is a duplicate and therefore should not be answered. See the [help] for more details.