# Unparseable date error format in Spring Boot Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

```java
MongoCollection<Document> Profile_List = db.getCollection("Profile_List");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD"); 
Date todaydate = format.parse(new Date().toString()); 
ArrayList<Document> activeList=profile.find(Filters.regex("lastActive",todayDate.toString())).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

This is the code what we have written. We are getting an “Unparseable date error”. Can someone please help?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime` and/or `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
Date todaydate = format.parse(new Date().toString());
```

The expression `new Date().toString()` does not return a string that conforms to the format `yyyy-MM-DD`, so if you try to parse it as if it is formatted that way, you will get an exception.

If you want a `Date` object that represents the current date and time, simply do this:

```
Date todaydate = new Date();
```

No need to convert the `Date` object to a string and trying to parse it.

If you need a string with the current date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` then do this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String todaydate = format.format(new Date());
```

Note: You used `DD` in your date format string but you most likely meant `dd`. See the [API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Got it, but I need to convert the string into Mongo DB date format, 2020-05-26T14:34:27.664Z

Comment: That's ISO-8601 format. [Format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914404/how-to-get-current-moment-in-iso-8601-format-with-date-hour-and-minute/33532945).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the current date string in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can do format it like this

```java
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```