# Why I can't parse this date format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ?

Tags: android, date, kotlin, date-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string date to a date . My string date is : 2021-12-16T11:00:00.000Z.

I have the follwing code to parse it to a date object:

```
val stringDate = "2021-12-16T16:42:00.000Z"
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
var consultationDate = sdf.parse(stringDate)
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-12-16T11:00:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `Z` the same way you use `T` for the parser to recognize the character in format

```
val stringDate = "2021-12-16T16:42:00.000Z"
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
var consultationDate = sdf.parse(stringDate)
```

Comment: I don’t know how SimpleDateFormat works but this seems wrong. You should never escape/ignore the Z. It means UTC timezone . If you escape it you will be discarding the timezone information from the date.  Try to parse with yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX or yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX.

Comment: Seems like you can not use more than 3 X with SimpleDateFormat. Not sure what you need to pass for the timezone if Z is not working but make sure the parsing is not discarding the UTC timezone. As it is it seems to me that it will parse it using the current timezone.

Comment: Try using XXX or XX. if you want to escape the Z you need to set the timezone of the parser to UTC and make sure the timezone always comes with Z. maybe this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914498/2303865

Answer (score 5):

As @Leo Dabus mentioned *You should never escape/ignore the Z. It means UTC timezone* . - as it will parse it using current timezone.

Also you shouldn't be using `SimpleDateFormat` as it's [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Use `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` to parse the date in the specific zone.

```
val date = "2021-12-16T16:42:00.000Z" // your date
// date is already in Standard ISO format so you don't need custom formatted
val dateTime : ZonedDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date).toZonedDateTime()  // parsed date 
// format date object to specific format if needed
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm") 
Log.e("Date 1", dateTime.format(formatter)) // output : Dec 16, 2021 16:42
```

Above date in the UTC timezone, if you want you can convert it into your system default timezone using `withZoneSameInstant`

```
val defaultZoneTime: ZonedDateTime = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
Log.e("Date 1", defaultZoneTime.format(formatter)) // output : Dec 16, 2021 22:12
```

**Note:**  `ZonedDateTime` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 enable desugaring.

In your app module's `build.gradle`, add `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled`

```
 compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```